# failing to compare variable string in ansible loop when condition resulting skip

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Team: I have already defined the var device_pattern in defaults/main.yaml and am referring it or using it for compare against ansible_facts but I get SKIPPED result.  it is not right syntax to find string? what is the catch?

when below is skipped though that string exists in the item value..

```
device_pattern: "nvme"
```

```
11:14:47  skipping: [node1] => (item=nvme1n1)  => {
11:14:47      "ansible_loop_var": "item",
11:14:47      "changed": false,
11:14:47      "item": "nvme1n1",
11:14:47      "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
11:14:47  }
```

task is

```
#MDM RAID0 All available free unmounted devices
- name: "Perform MDM Raid0 on all qualifying available devices on any cpu node"
  include_tasks:
    file: pfm_all_available_devices_mdm.yml
    apply:
      tags: pfm_all_available_devices_mdm
  when:
    - {{ device_pattern }} in ansible_devices[item]
  with_items: "{{ ansible_devices }}"
```

device info looks like below in facts

```
ok: [node1] => (item=nvme2n1) => {
   "ansible_devices[item]": {
       "holders": [],
       "host": "Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961",
       "links": {
           "ids": [
               "nvme-SAMSUNG_MZQLW960HMJP-00003_S35XNX0KA01405",
               "nvme-eui.333558304ba014050025385800000001"
           ],
           "labels": [],
           "masters": [],
           "uuids": []
       },
       "model": "SAMSUNG MZQLW960HMJP-00003",
       "partitions": {},
       "removable": "0",
       "rotational": "0",
       "sas_address": null,
       "sas_device_handle": null,
       "scheduler_mode": "none",
       "sectors": "1875385008",
       "sectorsize": "512",
       "size": "894.25 GB",
       "support_discard": "512",
       "vendor": null,
       "virtual": 1
   },
   "ansible_loop_var": "item",
   "item": "nvme2n1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out..

I have to compare on the item itself as it is already pulled from the loop with_items

```
#MDM RAID0 All available free unmounted devices
- name: "Perform MDM Raid0 on all qualifying available devices on any cpu node"
  include_tasks:
    file: pfm_all_available_devices_mdm.yml
    apply:
      tags: pfm_all_available_devices_mdm
  when:
    - {{ device_pattern }} in item
  with_items: "{{ ansible_devices }}"
```